# Como imprimir uma variável javascript dentro de uma tag html?

Tags: javascript, html

Como imprimir uma variável javascript dentro de uma tag html?

```
<script>
  (function() {
     var PORCENTAGEM = '25%';
  })();       
</script>

<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: IMPRIMIR PORCENTAGEM AQUI"></div>
</div>
```

Alguma luz?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode selecionar o elemento pela nome da classe e setar o valor do atributo, exemplo:

**Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9gX5/)**

```
(function() {
    var porcentagem = '25%';
    document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0].setAttribute("style","width:"+porcentagem);
  })();
```

**Edit:** 

Só para complementar, poderia ainda ser feito com jQuery de forma mais enxuta:

```
$(function(){
   var porcentagem = '25%';
   $('.progress-bar').width(porcentagem);
});
```

**Demo2: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9gX5/5/)**

Answer (score 5):

Para mudar o CSS de elementos diretamente via javascript pode fazer assim:

```
document.querySelector('.progress-bar').style.width = PORCENTAGEM;
```

Neste caso vai selecionar o primeiro elemento com classe "progress-bar" e mudar-lhe a largura para o valor que a variável PORCENTAGEM tiver no momento.

Não tenho a certeza como vai atualizar o valor da porcentagem.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/9LT7J/

**Já agora** podia fazer o que quer com o `<progress>` do HTML5, nesse caso faria assim:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <progress max="100" class="progress-bar" value="0"></progress>
</div>
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/9LT7J/1/